# AndroidX and Jetifier migration 3rd dependencies. Quick question

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, androidx

I have a question about migration. Should I also fix 3rd dependencies and create patches for them or it is not necessary? Example https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker/issues/683. Thanks for your help.